# Azure SQL Server tempdb full

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Seems like my tempdb is full, I'm not really sure if Azure should purge or auto grown the tempdb size but heres what happens when I try to do an ALT+F1 command on SMSS

> Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Procedure sys.sp_helpindex, Line 69 The
>   transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full due to
>   'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.

and then I type

> DBCC SQLPERF('logspace')
>
> tempdb    6757,992    100,0005

Is there anyway to purge/clean/increase this space?

Comment: Can you share the exact repro steps for us to repro the issue

Answer (score 2):

Problem was a dead transaction, killing it restored the tempdb.

On a side note, it's not possible to increase tempdb size on Azure SQL

Answer (score 1):

Was able to fix the issue by killing the dead transaction.
Run below query to get list of long running transactions:

```
select * from sys.dm_tran_database_transactions
```

Run below query to get session id of transaction:

```
select * from  sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

Identify the session and kill the session:

```
kill sessionId
```

**This will free the tempdb log.**